# Alternatives to ImageMagick for resizing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, image-processing, imagemagick, image-resizing

I am having some serious trouble installing ImageMagick and RMagick on my Windows 7 computer.

I was just wondering if there were any other easier to setup alternatives that work with Ruby on Rails and allow image re-sizing and cropping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ruby Toolbox has a big list of Image Processing tools you could try:

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/image_processing

If you're just having trouble with RMagick, maybe try [Mini Magick](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/mini_magick)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the suggested alternatives! The real nightmare is trying to install ImageMagick and it's dependancies on Windows. I am seriously debating getting a Mac just to use homebrew to install it - Does anyone know if this makes it significantly easier?

Comment: You don't have to pay money for mac, just use ubuntu!

Comment: I've used image_science gem with the FreeImage library on Mac OS X and Linux, precisely because RMagick is such a pain to get working. I have no experience with it on Windows, so YMMV, but it seems possible. http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/requirements.html http://rubygems.org/gems/image_science